# When should I use KnockoutJS Components vs. Templates?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

So trying to get my hands dirty with KnockoutJS 3.2. I've read the docs and I've successfully implemented components within my current project. I don't use an AMD, so I'm just using script elements to hold the views.

My question is: If i'm not using the asynchronous loading features, is there any real practical difference to using components rather than templates?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They aren't completely different. Components are made up of templates (html) and data/logic (view model i.e. JavaScript). When you have a modular view you want to attach a view model to you can utilize components. Here's a link discussing components a bit more: http://www.knockmeout.net/2014/06/knockout-3-2-preview-components.html

Comment: I did see that post. I think I'm trying to figure out when to choose one vs the other. I would argue that templates are also made up of HTML and data/logic that I pass in when I invoke the template, same as a component. Given a piece of code I want to reuse, what is the decision tree for choosing one vs the other?

Comment: you are right, based on my understanding it wraps around the template binding. That being said, its much easier to reuse components than templates. It also lets you create custom elements and I'm assuming will probably have some lifecycle callbacks you can utilize in next releases. It seems to allow Knockout to be easier to use for building SPAs.

Comment: So potentially safe to say start using components as the higher level abstraction, with templates potentially being deprecated or encapsulated as part of the component implementation?

Answer (score 19):

#### General description of both

As stated in the other answer, a template is only a piece of HTML which can be bound to a viewmodel, or viewmodel section. And a component is composed of a template, and its corresponding viewmodel. Besides, this viewmodel, apart from observables can include some simple business logic, and functionality to communicate with the server.

#### Coupling and encapsulation

Another important difference is the coupling. A template it's bound to the main viewmodel, and its bound to the main viewmodel's observables, so it's highly coupled to the viewmodel: a change in the viewmodel will break the template, and viceversa. So, if you're reusing a template in several places, and you change it, you have to correct the corresponding viewmodels.

A component is bound to its own viewmodel. It's only coupled to the main viewmodel if there are parameters provided from it. This means that you can easily change the component template as well as the component viewmodel, and, if there are no parameters, or you don't change them, nothing will be broken.

So using components helps in decoupling and modularizing.

#### Communication between main viewmodel and component

The last section is a double edged sword: if there is a high interaction between the main viewmodel and the template or component, it's much easier to use a template, because all the logic and properties are held in the main viewmodel and the interactions are easily implemented. If you used a component you'd need to provide complex parameters, or even make something to allow the component to expose functionality to the main viewmodel.

#### Polymorphism

It's not strange to have some parts of an application that require different behaviors and visualization to solve the same kind of task. For example, let's imagine you have to implement a payment system in your application: if you accept for example paypal and credit card payment you have two different visualization and functionalities. If you used templates, you'd need to have the particular implementation of each payment system in the main viewmodel. If you used components, they'd share a common interface (parameters) but each of them would have its own implementation. If tomorrow you had to include a new payment system, it would be easy to implement a new component with the common interface.

*NOTE: pay attention to the last paragraph*

#### Binding

In the case of a template the binding it's not done at the template level, but inside it. I.e. each element inside the template must be bound to observables of the main viewmodel. In the case of a component the binding is much simpler: at most, it requires the component name and the parameters, if they exist.

#### Component registration and custom tags

If you register the component you can use custom tags. This makes the views more easyly readable and understandable: instead of specifying the component name in a binding, you use a tag with the component name, and parameters are passed as attributes.

#### Dynamic loading

If you use templates you have to dynamically load them by yourself, and, as this is an asynchronous task, you'll have to take care of using the template only when it's already available. That's way in most occasions you'll use inline templates. This is not good if they must be reused in several places.

If you have used some AMD implementation, like require.js, and you understand the benefits of this technology, you'll be happy to know that you can easily use AMD to load component templates and viewmodels. One of the advantages is that you don't have to worry about the template or component being available when you need to use them.

#### Testability

No matter if you do manual or automated tests, it's much easier to test a bunch of independent components, one by one, that to test a complex viewmodel with or without templates.

#### My choice

So far, I've exposed facts about templates, and components, and I've tried not to show my personal preferences. However, in this last section, I must say that in most situations I prefer to use components for their advantages:

- modularity
- low coupling
- easy reuse
- testability
- binding syntax
- (optional) dynamic loading

#### However, templates are also a better fit on some occasions

The last paragraph have to do with big applications. If you're dealing with small applications or simply enhancements of interfaces rendered by another technology (like ASP.NET MVC), you'll probably get none of the advantages of using components. So, you don't need them.

There are other cases when it's not worth using components. For example, if you have to show a list (JavaScript array) of items which have different properties which must be shown in a different way, it's easier to use templates. Note that the choice in this case is because each of the instances doesn't have a complex viewmodel with a lot of functionality, but a simple bunch of properties. In this particular case it's not only not worth, but it can also be counterproductive to use components.

You can understand this last example as polymorphism. But, in this case it's nearly "visual" polymorphism. I.e. each kind of item must be shown in a different way, but there is no need to implement any special logic in each of the components.

**However**, even in this case, if the templates are complex enough, or must be used in many different places, it's also much better to use a simple component that includes the template as well as a parameter that receives the whole item. So, even in this case, it's not a bad idea to use components.

If you'd read this far, thank you, and I hope you have some criteria to help you choosing the best option.